# How to find XMM max value

Tags: assembly, x86, max, simd, sse

I need to find the maximum value in an xmm register. Now in the code that I'm writing there is this section:

```
comiss xmm2,xmm4        ; if(R[i*M+j]>Rmax)
ja UpateRmax
```

Now this is the scalar version. I'm trying to optimize to a packed version but I can't figure out how to take the maximum value from the hypothetical 4 values in xmm2, once I tested them with the 4 values in xmm2 .

Could you help?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do, but consider maintaining 4 maximums in the loop, and pick the biggest of those after the loop when speed no longer matters.

Comment: I assume you have four 16 bit values in `xmm2`? Please elaborate on your problem.  Consider using `pmaxsw`.

Comment: I'm guessing its 4 x float we're talking about here, in which case you can just use `maxps` inside the loop and then a horizontal max at the end (use 2 x `maxps` and 2 x shifts).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: yes, i have 4 floats in my xmm0 register. When the loops come to the step that i posted i need to compare that 4 floats with a single value contained in xmm2 and eventually replace it if the control goes well. Which one of the instructions you suggested should i use?

Comment: @PietroGerace all of them, it takes 4 operations to compute the horizontal maximum. That's why it's suggested to delay the horizontal part until after the loop.